# Dynamically Add Tabs to DevExpress DXTabControl WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I am having few menu items and on click of each menu item, I need to load up corresponding ViewModel as a new tab. To achieve this I have taken below approach:

```
 <dx:DXTabControl OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Margin="2" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" dxlc:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Client"
                             Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
                <dx:DXTabControl.View>                        
                    <dx:TabControlScrollView ShowHeaderMenu="True" ShowHiddenTabItemsInHeaderMenu="False" HeaderLocation="Top" HeaderOrientation="Horizontal" AllowAnimation="True" AllowHideTabItems="True" AutoHideScrollButtons="True" 
                                             ScrollViewer.PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" ScrollButtonsShowMode="WhenNeeded"/>
                </dx:DXTabControl.View>
                <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </dx:DXTabControl>
```

and in ViewModel (C#):

```
 public ObservableCollection<DXTabItem> Workspaces
    {
        get { return workspaces; }
        set { this.Set<ObservableCollection<DXTabItem>>("Workspaces", ref this.workspaces, value); }
    }
```

and to load the ViewModel:

```
Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<DXTabItem>() { new DXTabItem() { Header = header,
            Content = contentDetails, IsSelected= true, AllowHide = (((WorkspaceViewModel)contentDetails).AllowTabHiding) ? DefaultBoolean.True: DefaultBoolean.False } };
```

This approach works well, and gives me the desired behavior. But I do like to get rid off DXTabItem from my ViewModel, as this makes the ViewModel aware of the View. Please let me know the best way to tackle this.

Thanks!
Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dmitry for your input. Your input led me to the right direction and I found my answer in below mentioned link:
[DevExpress Help](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q306393)

In short this is how I have implemented:

```
  public class TabContainer
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string AllowHide { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public ViewModelBase Content { get; set; }
}
```

And Xaml looks like this:

```
<dx:DXTabControl OverridesDefaultStyle="True" Margin="2" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0" dxlc:DockLayoutControl.Dock="Client"
                                 Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
                    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="dx:DXTabItem">
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                            <Setter Property="AllowHide"  Value="{Binding AllowHide}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected"  Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                        </Style>                       
                    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <dx:DXTabControl.View>                        
                        <dx:TabControlScrollView ShowHeaderMenu="True" ShowHiddenTabItemsInHeaderMenu="False" HeaderLocation="Top" HeaderOrientation="Horizontal" AllowAnimation="True" AllowHideTabItems="True" AutoHideScrollButtons="True" 
                                                 ScrollViewer.PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" ScrollButtonsShowMode="WhenNeeded"/>
                    </dx:DXTabControl.View>
                    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                </dx:DXTabControl>
```

Thanks!
Sid

Answer (score 3):

When binding the `DXTabControl` in MVVM-manner you should not use the `DXTabItems` in ViewModel's code. Just bind your data-collection to the `DXTabControl.ItemsSource` property as it specified in [Binding to Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7978) help  article.
To specify the visual representation of tab items and headers use the `DXTabControl.ItemTemplate` and `DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate` templates respectively.

Please review the [How to bind DXTabControl to data](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3343) example for details.